# How to add days to pandas datetime until x day is met, while keeping the previous date?

Tags: python, pandas

This is what my data currently looks like:

```
STARTDATE   ENDDATE 
2021-07-16  2023-09-01
```

I would like to copy the row with the same information while adding plus 1 to the start date until I hit the end date.

What I'm looking to get:

```
STARTDATE   ENDDATE 
2021-07-16  2023-09-01
2021-07-17  2023-09-01
2021-07-18  2023-09-01
2021-07-19  2023-09-01
......................
2021-08-31  2023-09-01
2021-09-01  2023-09-01
```

Thanks!

Comment: does the input always have a unique row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.assign(STARTDATE = [pd.date_range(s,e) for s,e in zip(df['STARTDATE'],df['ENDDATE'])]).explode('STARTDATE')
```

or

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat((df['ENDDATE'] - df['STARTDATE']).dt.days.add(1))]
.assign(STARTDATE = lambda x: x['STARTDATE'] + pd.to_timedelta(x.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),'D')))
```

if your starting `df` does not have date values, try this first

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

output:

```
    STARTDATE   ENDDATE
0   2021-07-16  2023-09-01
0   2021-07-17  2023-09-01
0   2021-07-18  2023-09-01
0   2021-07-19  2023-09-01
0   2021-07-20  2023-09-01
... ... ...
0   2023-08-28  2023-09-01
0   2023-08-29  2023-09-01
0   2023-08-30  2023-09-01
0   2023-08-31  2023-09-01
0   2023-09-01  2023-09-01
```